# Unwanted variable behaviour when combining .each() with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function similar to the following (simplified here for brevity)

```
$('.somelement').each(function(){

    var me = $(this)

    var mydata = me.data('somedata')

    $.ajax({url:"phpfile.php?data=" + mydata}).done(function(returnedhtml){

        console.log(mydata)

    });

});
```

Each element with class `.someelement` has a different value for `somedata`.

When I look at the ajax call in firebug I see a different `mydata` passed to the php file.

But the `console.log(mydata)` is logging the same value each time (i.e. not always the value passed into the url in the ajax function)

I realize this may be caused by the asynchronous nature of the ajax call but even so, it seems 'buggy' to not be picking up the right `mydata` through the flow of code.   I tried adding `async:false` to the ajax call, and the problem goes away, but I get a warning that async:false is deprecated in the global thingy whatchamagig.

Is there a simple and correct way to do what I'm trying to do (retain variable consistency inside and outside of the `$.ajax` call inside each `each()` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use self-invoking functions ([IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression))

```
var mydata = me.data('somedata')
(function(data){
    $.ajax({"phpfile.php?data=" + mydata})
        .done(function(returnedhtml){
            console.log(data);          
        });
})(mydata);
```